# Text Color didn't change

Tags: flutter, flutter-textformfield

I try to use FocusNode() in TextFormField so it will detect when I focus on the TextFormField, the text above will have it's color changed. But it seems not working, what seems to be the problem?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQLrU.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignIn({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SignInState createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  bool isPasswordVisible = false;
  bool _isEmail = true;
  bool _isPassword = true;
  TextEditingController emailInput = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordInput = TextEditingController();
  FocusNode emailText = FocusNode();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                'Sign In to Coinify',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 24.0,
                  fontFamily: "Graphik",
                )
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20.0),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Email',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      color: emailText.hasFocus ? Colors.blue : Colors.black,
                      fontFamily: "Graphik",
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                  TextFormField(
                    focusNode: emailText,
                    controller: emailInput,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue)
                      ),
                      errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                      ),
                      focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)
                      ),
                      hintText: 'Enter your email',
                      errorText: _isEmail ? null : "Email must not be empty",
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20.0),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Password',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      fontFamily: "Graphik",
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: passwordInput,
                    obscureText: !isPasswordVisible,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue)
                      ),
                      errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                      ),
                      focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                      ),
                      hintText: 'Enter your password',
                      errorText: _isPassword ? null : "Password must not be empty",
                      suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            isPasswordVisible = !isPasswordVisible;
                          });
                        },
                        child: Icon(
                          isPasswordVisible ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 50.0),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  MouseRegion(
                    cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/forgot-password');
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'Forgot password?',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        )
                      )
                    )
                  ),
                  MouseRegion(
                    cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/privacy-policy');
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'Privacy policy',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        )
                      )
                    )
                  ),
                ]
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20.0),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if(emailInput.text == ""){_isEmail = false;}
                    else{_isEmail = true;}
                    if(passwordInput.text == ""){_isPassword = false;}
                    else{_isPassword = true;}
                    if(_isEmail && _isPassword) {Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/sign-in-code');}
                  });
                },
                child: Text(
                  "Sign in",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                    color: Colors.white
                  ),
                ),
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                    RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0))
                  ),
                  minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(Size.fromHeight(60.0)),
                  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue),
                  shadowColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent)
                ),
              )
            ]
          )
        ),
      )
    );  
  }
}
```

I have tried to change the color in the ternary operator and realized that the Color seems to stuck in false value

Answer (score 0):

The state is not changing when the focus is changed, therefore the text color doesn't change.

You must listen to the `FocusNode` changes and `setState` after any changes. Update your widget like this:

```dart
FocusNode emailText = FocusNode();
Color _emailTextColor = Colors.black;

_onEmailFocusChange() {
  setState(() {
    _emailTextColor = emailText.hasFocus ? Colors.blue : Colors.black;
  });
}

@override
void initState() {
  emailText.addListener(_onEmailFocusChange);
  super.initState();
}

@override
void dispose() {
  super.dispose();
  emailText.removeListener(_onEmailFocusChange);
  emailText.dispose();
}
```

Use `_emailTextColor` as your text color inside `TextStyle`.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a listener to focusNode value to detect where the TextFormField is being focused or not.

I prefer to use **ValueNotifier** and **ValueListenableBuilder** to rebuild only the Text widget not all the widgets in the screen.

```
final isEmailFocused = ValueNotifier<bool>(false);

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  emailText.addListener(() {
    isEmailFocused.value = emailText.hasFocus;
  });
}

@override
void dispose() {
  // don't forget to dispose all the inputs notifiers.
  emailText.dispose();
  emailInput.dispose();
  isEmailFocused.removeListener(() {});
  isEmailFocused.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}
```

In Build method I wrapped the Email Text Widget with **ValueListenableBuilder** widget to rebuild the widget if the emailInput is focused.

```
ValueListenableBuilder(
  valueListenable: isEmailFocused,
  builder: (BuildContext context, bool value, Widget? child) {
    return Text(
      'Email',
         style: TextStyle(
         fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
         fontSize: 16.0,
         color: value ? Colors.blue : Colors.black,
         fontFamily: "Graphik",
       ),
     );
   },
 ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You may add the `setState` method as a `listener` to the `FocusNode` object named `emailText`. This will change the color of the Text you want to change based on the focus on the TextField.

**Modified code:**

```
class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  bool isPasswordVisible = false;
  bool _isEmail = true;
  bool _isPassword = true;
  TextEditingController emailInput = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordInput = TextEditingController();
  FocusNode emailText = FocusNode();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    emailText.addListener(() => setState(() {}));
  }

  // Rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because your UI **is not rebuild** when you focus the TextField.
You must call the `setState()` to update your UI.

#### Method 1: Using your existing `FocusNode`

Since you have already creating the focus node and set color in the ternary operator, you just need to add the following code:

```
class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  ...
  FocusNode emailText = FocusNode();
  ...
  
  // add listener to your FocusNode
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    emailText.addListener(_onEmailFocusChange);
  }
  
  // the listener action is setting state when focus change
  void _onEmailFocusChange() {
    setState(() {});
    debugPrint("Email is focus: ${emailText.hasFocus.toString()}");
  }
  
  // don't forget to dispose your listener
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    emailText.removeListener(_onEmailFocusChange);
    emailText.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
    ...
    ...
  }
}
```

And this is your final code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignIn({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SignInState createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  bool isPasswordVisible = false;
  bool _isEmail = true;
  bool _isPassword = true;
  TextEditingController emailInput = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordInput = TextEditingController();
  FocusNode emailText = FocusNode();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    emailText.addListener(_onEmailFocusChange);
  }

  void _onEmailFocusChange() {
    setState(() {});
    debugPrint("Email is focus: ${emailText.hasFocus.toString()}");
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    emailText.removeListener(_onEmailFocusChange);
    emailText.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
              child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text('Sign In to Coinify',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 24.0,
                          fontFamily: "Graphik",
                        )),
                    SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Email',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                            color:
                                emailText.hasFocus ? Colors.blue : Colors.black,
                            fontFamily: "Graphik",
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                        TextFormField(
                          focusNode: emailText,
                          controller: emailInput,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue)),
                            errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                            ),
                            focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
                            hintText: 'Enter your email',
                            errorText:
                                _isEmail ? null : "Email must not be empty",
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Password',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                            fontFamily: "Graphik",
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                        TextFormField(
                          controller: passwordInput,
                          obscureText: !isPasswordVisible,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue)),
                            errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                            ),
                            focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                            ),
                            hintText: 'Enter your password',
                            errorText: _isPassword
                                ? null
                                : "Password must not be empty",
                            suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  isPasswordVisible = !isPasswordVisible;
                                });
                              },
                              child: Icon(
                                isPasswordVisible
                                    ? Icons.visibility
                                    : Icons.visibility_off,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 50.0),
                    Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          MouseRegion(
                              cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
                              child: GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    Navigator.pushNamed(
                                        context, '/forgot-password');
                                  },
                                  child: Text('Forgot password?',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.blue,
                                      )))),
                          MouseRegion(
                              cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
                              child: GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    Navigator.pushNamed(
                                        context, '/privacy-policy');
                                  },
                                  child: Text('Privacy policy',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.blue,
                                      )))),
                        ]),
                    SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          if (emailInput.text == "") {
                            _isEmail = false;
                          } else {
                            _isEmail = true;
                          }
                          if (passwordInput.text == "") {
                            _isPassword = false;
                          } else {
                            _isPassword = true;
                          }
                          if (_isEmail && _isPassword) {
                            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/sign-in-code');
                          }
                        });
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        "Sign in",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                            color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      style: ButtonStyle(
                          shape:
                              MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                  RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(5.0))),
                          minimumSize:
                              MaterialStateProperty.all(Size.fromHeight(60.0)),
                          backgroundColor:
                              MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue),
                          shadowColor:
                              MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent)),
                    )
                  ])),
        ));
  }
}
```

#### Method 2: Using `Focus` widget

The second method is more simple, it just only wrap your `TextFormField` with `Focus` widget and call the `setState` in the `onFocusChange` like below:

```
Focus(   // <- wrap with this
  onFocusChange: (focus) {
    setState(() {});   // <- and call setState
    print("Email is focus: $focus");
  },
  child: TextFormField(
    focusNode: emailText,
    controller: emailInput,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      ...
    ),
  ),
),
```

And this is your final code using this method:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignIn({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SignInState createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  bool isPasswordVisible = false;
  bool _isEmail = true;
  bool _isPassword = true;
  TextEditingController emailInput = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordInput = TextEditingController();
  FocusNode emailText = FocusNode();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
              child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text('Sign In to Coinify',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 24.0,
                          fontFamily: "Graphik",
                        )),
                    SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Email',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                            color:
                                emailText.hasFocus ? Colors.blue : Colors.black,
                            fontFamily: "Graphik",
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                        Focus(
                          onFocusChange: (focus) {
                            setState(() {});
                            print("Email is focus: $focus");
                          },
                          child: TextFormField(
                            focusNode: emailText,
                            controller: emailInput,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)),
                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue)),
                              errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                              ),
                              focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
                              hintText: 'Enter your email',
                              errorText:
                                  _isEmail ? null : "Email must not be empty",
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Password',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                            fontFamily: "Graphik",
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                        TextFormField(
                          controller: passwordInput,
                          obscureText: !isPasswordVisible,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue)),
                            errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                            ),
                            focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                            ),
                            hintText: 'Enter your password',
                            errorText: _isPassword
                                ? null
                                : "Password must not be empty",
                            suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  isPasswordVisible = !isPasswordVisible;
                                });
                              },
                              child: Icon(
                                isPasswordVisible
                                    ? Icons.visibility
                                    : Icons.visibility_off,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 50.0),
                    Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          MouseRegion(
                              cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
                              child: GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    Navigator.pushNamed(
                                        context, '/forgot-password');
                                  },
                                  child: Text('Forgot password?',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.blue,
                                      )))),
                          MouseRegion(
                              cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
                              child: GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    Navigator.pushNamed(
                                        context, '/privacy-policy');
                                  },
                                  child: Text('Privacy policy',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.blue,
                                      )))),
                        ]),
                    SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          if (emailInput.text == "") {
                            _isEmail = false;
                          } else {
                            _isEmail = true;
                          }
                          if (passwordInput.text == "") {
                            _isPassword = false;
                          } else {
                            _isPassword = true;
                          }
                          if (_isEmail && _isPassword) {
                            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/sign-in-code');
                          }
                        });
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        "Sign in",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                            color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      style: ButtonStyle(
                          shape:
                              MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                  RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(5.0))),
                          minimumSize:
                              MaterialStateProperty.all(Size.fromHeight(60.0)),
                          backgroundColor:
                              MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue),
                          shadowColor:
                              MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent)),
                    )
                  ])),
        ));
  }
}
```

And this is the result:

[image: demo]

Hopefully it can solve your problem, Thanks

Comment: thank you very much for the answer, if you don't mind, could you explain to me is there any difference between the 2 method? Because in the other page, I am not using the set state only use the FocusNode and it works, but when I compare it the one without set state is slower. Btw thank you again for the answer I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are not updating the state and resulting in ui change. Use `Focus` widget and setState in `onFocusChange` callback.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _isNodeFocus = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: const Text("My app"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Email',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                fontSize: 16.0,
                color: _isNodeFocus ? Colors.blue : Colors.yellow,
                fontFamily: "Graphik",
              ),
            ),
            Focus(
              onFocusChange: (hasFocus) {
                setState(() {
                  _isNodeFocus = hasFocus;
                });
              },
              child: TextFormField(),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```